# Create a drop down list of years in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

How would I create a drop down list of years (say between NOW 2011 and 100 years ago) which the user could then select the appropriate year.

Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Noel

EDIT Solution:

Just in case anybody needs this there were a few minor errors in Philippe's code the following works for me:

```
Dim myYearArray(100) As String, myYearList As String, i As Integer

For i = 0 To 100
    myYearArray(i) = CStr(Year(DateAdd("yyyy", i * -1, Date)))
Next i
myYearList = Join(myYearArray, ";")

MyForm.MyCmbBox.RowSource = myYearList
```

Comment: While this might be sufficient for a list of 100 years, as a generalized solution, it's problematic because there is a finite limit on the number of characters that can be assigned to the Rowsource property. A better solution is a callback function. The Access help shows exactly how to create them.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton cheers for the advice appreciated

Comment: Doesn't work! Throws error !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that the control you want to populate is called myYear, and its rowsource type is set to "value list". You just have to generate its rowsource, as a string, where values are separated by ";". You could do it this way:

```
Dim myYearArray(100) as string, myYearList as string, i as integer

for i = 1 to 100
    myYearList(i) = cstr(year(dateAdd("yyyy", i * -1,date()))
next i
myYearList = join(myYearList,";")
myForm.myYear.rowSource = myYearList
```

The combobox generated will begin (first value) with the current year and contain the last 100 years. I did not test it, and I might have missed a bracket or a quote, but the idea is here.

Comment: This does the job brilliantly Phillipe, needed minor tweaking but works great and avoids creating a new table, Cheers.

Comment: @Thameem my original code was written on the fly, without testing. Please use the debugged version of it, available in the question's EDIT section.

Answer (score 3):

Put the years you want in your dropdown in a table and bind your dropdown to your table.

Comment: So at the start of each new year I would need to add a year to the table? It seems like quite a laboured unsophisticated way to do this, not that I'm questioning your approach. I was hoping that it would be possible to place a statement in the rowsource property of the combo box, such as DATE (yyyy) BETWEEN NOW and 1900. Maybe its just wishfull thinking!!

Comment: yeah, easy for you, not so easy for Access to implement.  Yes, once a year, you'd have to add a new row to the table, or you can add a function to check if you need to do that when your end users start your application.

Answer (score 2):

Beth gave you part of the answer, but to be more specific: Set the Rowsource property of your combo box to the Years table (or to an SQL statement that selects that column from that table--possibly with other columns as well, depending on what you want to do with it). You can set the Control Source somewhere else to store the user's selection.